# Remote Desktops on Vista/Win7 x64?

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, windows-7, windows-vista, windows

Is the **Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 Administration Tools Pack** the only way to install the **Remote Desktops** MMC add-in on Vista/Win7 x64 workstations?

Are there any better, low cost alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is the RD MMC add-in uses the /console switch for console connections, this has been superseded by /admin in later versions of windows though, so it doesn't really work any more

I've been successfully using [RD Tabs](http://www.avianwaves.com/Tech/Tools/RDTabs/), and a commercial product from [vissionapp](http://www.visionapp.com) to fill this need for me, both seem to work very well for what I need

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Terminals over at CodePlex (http://www.codeplex.com/Terminals). Its a great free little multi-terminal program. Not without its flaws, but still a very good app.

Answer (score 1):

Your going want the [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en)
.

Once you install this update, go into control panel, prgrams, and turn on windows features.

The Remote desktops mmc is under the Role Administration tools branch.

Comment: Hey Russ thats awesome, I thought they had removed it completely! (maybe that was in Vista?)  does this take into account the change from /console to /admin and provide backward compatibility where required?

Comment: @Ryan, There was a RSAT for Vista as well. ( Vista was a bit after RTM though, which was annoying ).

I can't speak specificaly to the /console to /admin, but I don't know of any reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: @Ryan, sorry I forgot to speak to the backward compatibility. I use the windows 7 RSAT to remote desktop to Windows 2000 systems all the way through Windows 2008 R2/Windows 7 Systems.